# __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_react___default.a.memo is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I just connect the app with redux and react-redux connect function, together with state and dispatches. It compiled without problems but the results are not showing. And it looks like below.

I tried to find it and found that I have to change the react version.

```
$ sudo npm install --save react@16.4.0 react-dom@16.4.0
```

But it didn't work.

I am following this tutorial.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BxzO2M7QcZw

[image: Screenshot of error message as given in question title]

[image: Screenshot of the source code]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you're using wrong version of `React`, `React.memo` is introduced with version `16.6.0` so, try this command to install the right version

```
npm install --save react@16.6.0 react-dom@16.6.0
```

for more info click [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/23/react-v-16-6.html)

Comment: Thanks for the version numbers. Installing `react` at `^16.6.0` solved the issue I was having!

Answer (score 11):

This had happened to me as well. This happens when dependencies version gets updated, and the dependencies of the YouTube video you are watched has an old version.

Hence, replace the following dependencies in the `package.json` file:

```
"react": "^16.4.1",
"react-dom": "^16.4.1",
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
"redux": "^4.0.0",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
```

and run `npm install`.

Since the `connect()` function connects a React component to a Redux store,
`react, redux` need to be version supported. If you are willing to use newest dependencies please refer the [Redux](https://redux.js.org/api/api-reference) documentation.

The above method should solve your problem.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! But how do I know which version of `redux`, `react-redux`, `redux-thunk` are compatible each other?

Comment: Generally the package manager figures this out for you (each `./node_modules/my-cool-module/` has their own `package.json`). Note that in the original question specific versions were given so the package manager will install those specific versions

Answer (score 2):

That's because `@material-ui/styles` has a peer dependency on `react >= 16.7.0-alpha.0 and react-dom >= 16.7.0-alpha.0` that include hooks.
To use `@material-ui/styles`, change your **react and react-dom** dependencies like this:

"dependencies": {

```
...

"react": "^16.7.0-alpha.2",
"react-dom": "^16.7.0-alpha.2",
...
```

},

Answer (score 0):

Find out which version of react-redux version you are using and then go to https://react-redux.js.org/versions.  Click on the documentation associated with your version. You should see something like this:

Installation

React Redux 7.1 requires React 16.8.3 or later.

Update your react in package.json to the appropriate version and install.