# material UI causes __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_react___default.a.memo is not a function Error

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm receiving this error upon running react app caused by material ui

```
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_react___default.a.memo is not a function. (In '__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_react___default.a.memo(TouchRipple)', '__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3_react___default.a.memo' is undefined)
./node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/ButtonBase/TouchRipple.js
node_modules/@material-ui/core/esm/ButtonBase/TouchRipple.js:312
  309 | export default withStyles(styles, {
  310 |   flip: false,
  311 |   name: 'MuiTouchRipple'
> 312 | })(withMuiName(React.memo(TouchRipple)));
  313 |
```

I updated react/react-dom to 16.6.0 or re-run npm install based on an almost identical [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55689238/webpack-imported-module-4-react-default-a-memo-is-not-a-function) but it didn't resolved my problem. What should I do to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Either update your react dependencies or downgrade material-ui. I chose the first option, here's how I did it:
1. open package.json
2. Under dependencies, change react and react-dom to this -> `"react": "^16.7.0-alpha.2",
"react-dom": "^16.7.0-alpha.2",`
3. Save and open command prompt
4. navigate to file path and run 'npm install'
5. your react should be up to date with the specified version and material-ui should work