# React.memo is not a function in 16.13.0

Tags: reactjs

**TestComponent.js**

```
import React from "react";

function TestComponent(props) {
  return <div>{props.id}</div>;
}

function arePropsEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
  return prevProps.id === nextProps.id;
}

export default React.memo(TestComponent)(arePropsEqual);
```

The above component is throwing the following error:
**TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.memo(...) is not a function**
I know this question has been asked a lot of time [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55689238/webpack-imported-module-4-react-default-a-memo-is-not-a-function), [here](https://forums.expo.io/t/react-default-memo-is-not-a-function/21623) and [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/1239) but all of these questions have one thing in common, they all are using version below than **16.6.0** and obviously it won't work in the version below than this as **React memo** was released in this version.
But I'm using **16.13.0** (screenshot attached) but still getting this error.
**Package.json**
[image]

**Screenshot of error:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
export default React.memo(TestComponent)(arePropsEqual);
```

do:

```
export default React.memo(TestComponent, arePropsEqual);
```

Comment: Oh man! .. It resolved my issue.. How can I have a syntax error and still coudn't understand the problem..
Thanks alot !